# function always returns null

Tags: sql-server, recursion, user-defined-functions

I have written a function to find the base unit of something(the data are stored in a table). 
This is what the table looks like :

```
pcode      packname                                           baseunit
1          BU                                                 0
2          DU                                                 1
3          du1                                                2
4          tab                                                0
5          strip                                              4
6          box                                                5
7          cart                                               6
```

Here I want to return the base name for a given code. For example, if i call the function with '7' it should return "tab". The baseunit column contains the value 0 if it a base unit, otherwise pcode of its baseunit. I want to find the top most item in the hierarchy. 
I have written a function for this, and it always return null.

```
alter function [dbo].[findbasepack1](@derpack varchar(10))
returns nvarchar(50) 
as
begin
  declare @baseunit numeric(18,0)
  declare @pname nvarchar(50)
  set @baseunit= (select baseunit from packing where pcode=@derpack)
  if( @baseunit = 0)
  begin
    set @pname = ( select packname from packing where pcode = @baseunit)
  end
  else
  begin
    set @pname = dbo.findbasepack1(@baseunit)
  end
return @pname
end
GO
```

I have tried in both recursion and iteration but it doesnt seem to work. It will be a great deal of help if someone can point out where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Interesting syntax. I always use `SELECT @panme = packname from ...`.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to step through the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to correct some erros, this is the code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[findbasepack1]
(
    @derpack int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(10)
AS
begin
  declare @baseunit numeric(18,0)
  declare @pname nvarchar(10)
  set @baseunit= (select baseunit from packing where pcode=@derpack)
  if( @baseunit = 0)
  begin
    set @pname = ( select packname from packing where pcode=@derpack)
  end
  else
  begin
    set @pname = dbo.findbasepack1(@baseunit)
  end
return @pname
END
```

This is the table I used

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[packing](
    [pcode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [packname] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [baseunit] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

For input 7 it returns 'tab'. There was a problem in the second select where you compare 'pcode' to '@baseunit' instead of '@derpack'.

Hope that helps. As a side note, you could also select both 'baseunit' and 'pname' columns in a single select instead of doing it twice.

Comment: nice, it's worth mentioning there's a maximum recursive limit of 32 (in SQL Server 2012) - hopefully the data in his table won't go down this deep.

Comment: This works! thank you. @Phill thanks for the info, I will try to use iteration then.